# Move, not copy, photos from iPhone to Windows

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, photos

I would like to move (not copy) my photos from an iPhone 7 (latest iOS) to my Windows PC (Windows 10, latest patches).

I am able to copy photos, but not to delete them from iOS.

I would like to:

1. Copy an entire folder (e.g. "114Apple") from iOS to Windows.
2. Delete all photos under that iOS folder.

I am able to do 1 but not 2.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an obvious way to move files from an Apple device to Windows:

1. connect the USB cable
2. device appears in Windows as another filesystem
3. cut and pasted files from the Apple directory tree to the
   Windows tree

In my case, I think my device is aging, and perhaps the SSD is starting to have errors. I can cut/paste files from Apple to Windows, but after a number of files are transferred, I get an error saying "Device not reachable". I disconnect the cable, wait 10 min and start over. A few files are moved each time, but this is a laborious method. Wonder if there is an easier way.

Comment: I wonder if you could find that directory on jailbroken iOS and just delete it on-device